# Null check operator used on a null value problem, I am very confused

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter app.
I have made a subcollection **products** in **users** collections. It will show to all when a user will log in to their account. When the user clicks on the **My Products** button it will only show those products which are created by the login user. I user stream builder and use this **FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.doc(LoginUser!.uid)
.collection('products')
.snapshots() ,** to get the data.
But when I click on the button it throws an exception. Which provide on the screen shots.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  UserProductList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserProductListState createState() => _UserProductListState();
}

class _UserProductListState extends State<UserProductList> {
 User? LoginUser;
 
@override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  getCurrentUser();
  
}

void getCurrentUser() async{
  var LoginUser=await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  print(LoginUser!.email);
  
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(LoginUser!.uid)
            .collection('products')
            .snapshots() ,
        builder:(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot){
          return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document){

              return  ElevatedButton(onPressed: getCurrentUser, child: Text('data'));

            }).toList(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This image shows the exceptions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst of all, `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is not a `Future` it doesn't need to be `await`ed. You can use it straight away in your `StreamBuilder`

```dart
.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? '')
```

Comment: sir, It's not working the **CircularProgressIndicator()** just showing in progress. I think my main problem with my **LoginUser** which is not accurate @enentis

Comment: Add a setState after getting the user, inside `getCurrentUser`

Comment: No sir, It's not working,  @esentis

Comment: Does the email of the user print ? Maybe the user is not logged.

Comment: Sir, When I press on the button to go to the page it's print authenticated id and email on my console, but after going to the page its throw the exceptions that's why I am not able to see that, but it's already logged in mode, I use email and password to log in then form that page I want to got this page to show my products.

Comment: ` @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }
User? LoginUser; 
   getCurrentUser() async {
    var LoginUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if(LoginUser==null){
      return 'User not login';
    }
   
    print(LoginUser.uid);
    print(LoginUser.email);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: getCurrentUser , child: Text('Id got')))
    );
  }
}
`It's getting the login user-id and email both @esentis

Comment: Editted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was by making the **currentUser** future by using **async and await**. that's why **steamBulder** did not get the user id to fetch the data and throwing error for null user.

````dart
void getCurrentUser() async{
  var LoginUser=await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  print(LoginUser!.email);
  
}``` 

So, I just remove this portion code and instead of that I just use this **var LoginUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;** to get my **login user Uid** and it's working perfectly
````